# Elasticsearch query with multiple fuzziness and weights

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write query that should combine match and fuzziness together on different fields. For each field will be assigned a different weight and if there is a match on that field, it should use this weight for the document's total sum. Then it should return documents with total sum >= some value.
Any suggestion ?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: did you try [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#query-dsl-function-score-query)?

Comment: Solved it with the function_score  and some functions: boost_mode: replace,  score_mode: sum and min_score.